# Saving JMS message sent on Topic into Gemfire using Spring

Tags: spring, jms, jms-topic, gemfire

the problem in that I am receiving JMS message on Topic, and I need to persist the message structure into GemFire (classic) region MessageStructInfo.

The message has data in its structure like 
**< messagenotification >
< fieldidentifierEndDate="2014-12-24" fieldidentifierStartDate="2014-12-07" fileName="filenotification.xml" directory="../filehostdirectory" />
< /messagenotification>**

I need to extract the fields data from message and persist into GemFire region.
**MessageStructInfo                                                                                fieldidentifierStartDate,

  fieldidentifierEndDate,
  fileName,
  directory,
  Status  - Additional (Received, Processed, Completed)**

I need this help.

Thanks
Rishi

Answer (score -1):

You can create object of your class, say Message (implementing `com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializable` interface), and stuff with fields extracted from the JMS message and store the object in the region.  You can store. Hope this helps.